# How to differentiate image and hexcode in Visual swatch attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I am working with Magento 2 to get attributes values. Now here I added on an attribute which name Swatch Image. in there I selected 2 options, one I selected hex code (#cdcdcd) and other options I selected Image.  Now I know how to get both values using option_id.
which are mentioned below.
for hex code

```
$opt_id = 26;
                        $swatchHelper=$objectManager->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data");
                        $attributeOptionIds = array($opt_id);
                        $swatches = $swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId($attributeOptionIds);
                        echo "<pre>";
                            print_r($swatches);
                        echo "</pre>";
                        if(sizeof($swatches) > 0 ){
                            echo "<pre>";
                            print_r($swatches[$opt_id]['value']);
                            echo "</pre>";
                        }
```

and for Image

```
$opt_id1 = 27;
    $swatchHelper_image=$objectManager->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
    $swatchCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');

    $swatch1 = $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$opt_id1);
    $item=$swatch1->getFirstItem();
    $ThumbImage1 =  $swatchHelper_image->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($ThumbImage);
```

here I added code for both which I know already option 26 is hex and 27 is image. but I want to differentialte it. 
I mean how can I recognize which is hex and which is image.

Please help me.

Comment: I got an answer thanks who started to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We need to write the below code for differentiating both values!

```
        $opt_id = 23;
        $swatchHelper_hex = $objectManager->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data");
        $attributeOptionIds = array($opt_id);
        $swatch2 = $swatchHelper_hex->getSwatchesByOptionsId($attributeOptionIds);
        if(!empty($swatch2)){
            if($swatch2[$opt_id]['type']==2){
                //image
                $opt_val = $swatch2[$opt_id]['value'];
            }else if($swatch2[$opt_id]['type']==1){
                //hexcode
                $opt_val = $swatch2[$opt_id]['value'];
            }
            echo $opt_val;
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
```